# How can I copy an eps file to clipboard/pasteboard?

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-carbon, eps, pasteboard

My program creates adobe ai or (eps) file and I want to copy it to pasteboard.
I copied sample ai object in adobe illustrator and Inspect pasteboard by "pasteboard inspector":

[image]

My code is below but copy nothing to pasteboard:

```
void copyEPS(CFDataRef data)
{
    OSStatus err = noErr;
    PasteboardRef theClipboard;

    err = PasteboardCreate(kPasteboardClipboard, &theClipboard);
    // err is 0
    err = PasteboardClear(theClipboard);
    // err is 0
    PasteboardSynchronize(theClipboard);

    err = PasteboardPutItemFlavor(theClipboard, (PasteboardItemID)1,
        CFSTR("AICB"), data, 0);
    // err is 0
    CFRelease(data);
}
```

How can I do it?
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

The type string for `PasteboardPutItemFlavor()` is a UTI, so it probably should be set to `CFSTR("com.adobe.encapsulated-postscript")` in this case.  Cocoa APIs can also be used with similar inputs.

Comment: I used "com.adobe.encapsulated-postscript" and eps data copied to pasteboard but InDesign or Illustrator doesnt paste It, if I use "dyn.ah62d4rv4gk8ycwndkk" as type, It paste to both that programs (accepted as eps) and everything is Ok, do you know how can generate the "dyn.ah62d4rv4gk8ycwndkk" string? I have been used UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag, but I dont know what pass to "inTag" param to generate "dyn.ah62d4rv4gk8ycwndkk". thanks.

Comment: I believe `UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag()` is the only way.  In this case, `kUTTagClassOSType` and `CFSTR("AICB")` seem like good values for the first two parameters.  Unfortunately I don't know if you'd get the same `dyn.*` string; I don't know if the string is the same on all Mac computers, or even if it's the same on your computer across reboots.  It is probably not reliable to use as a raw string.

Comment: The "dyn.agk8ycwndkk" generated with kUTTagClassOSType and CFSTR("AICB");